# Can't figure out why while loop is infinite

Tags: c++

My code uses what I thought would be a simple while loop. It checks if the `randCard` already exists in the vector I have and, if it does, makes a new `randCard`.

I've added `cout` statements within the loop to try to find which processes it's running through and discovered it's only running through the while loop, none of the nested for loops. The problem is as follows:

```cpp
    bool isSame = true;


    //Make sure they don't be the same cards

    while (isSame){
        cout << "While entered" << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < notToUse.size(); i++){
            if(randCard == notToUse.at(i)){
                randCard = rand() % 24;

            }
            cout << "First for ran" << endl;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < notToUse.size(); i++){
            if (randCard == notToUse.at(i)){
                cout << "Recheck loop" << endl;
                break;
            }
            else{
                cout << "Else ran" << endl;
                isSame = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

`randCard` is from a class of type Cards. The vector `notToUse` consists of cards indices that have already been used. The end `cout` statements end up looking like:

```
While entered
While entered
While entered
While entered
While entered
```

It seems like the for loops aren't even accessed. How can I fix this?

Comment: It appears like `notToUse` has 0 size, but it is impossible to debug with the code given. Try logging `notToUse.size()` outside the for loop and inside the while loop.

Comment: First thing I'd check is what `notToUse.size()` is.

Comment: Could you post enough code that we can test it and run it ourselves? (If there's a lot, use a site like pastebin.com). The first thing I'd check is to make sure that `notToUse.size()` is bigger than 0 (because if it's 0, it'll never enter the for loops)

Comment: *It checks if the randCard already exists in the vector I have and, if it does, makes a new randCard.* --  Going by that description, all of that code could have been replaced with a simple: `auto iter = std::find(notToUse.begin(), notToUse.end(), randCard); if (iter != notToUse.end()) randCard = rand%24;`

Comment: Thank you guys so much I can't believe I didn't look at that. The size was zero and that's what was causing the problem.

Comment: @Idalas -- You should have used the code in my comment.  Checking for an empty vector is not necessary.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yeah I have switched to using that code too. I had a feeling I had something more complicated than needed

Comment: @Idalas -- Basically if you're writing code that has the feeling that "this must have been done before, thousands of times", there is usually an STL algorithm or two that do the job.  Checking if a container contains a value is just one of those instances.

Comment: If anyone is still watching this thread, I have a side question: once I get a ```randCard``` that will work, I want to add it to the ```notToUse``` vector. However, this vector is a private member in the ```Cards``` class. I have discovered that ```notToUse.push_back(randCard)``` only pushes it back inside the constructor, and doesn't actually change the member. So the next time the number search is called, it starts with the empty vector again. Anyone know a fix to this?

Comment: @Idalas  -- Your latest request should be a separate question.  In short, write a function to return a reference to the member you're trying to change.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who might stumble upon this, the answer was resolved in the comments. The vector was of size 0, so the for loops didn't even run.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to us about it!